# rails mysql regex input not getting sanitized properly

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am doing the following on a rails 3 app

```
def test(str)
    User.where("name REGEXP ?",str).last
end
```

Using the format above, rails generally handles sanitizing the input. However it fails on few cases.

If I use

```
str = "hi\\"
```

I get this error:-

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Got error 'trailing backslash (\)' from regexp: SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE (name REGEXP 'hi\\') ORDER BY `users`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
```

If I use

```
str="hi("
```

I get this error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Got error 'parentheses not balanced' from regexp: SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE (name REGEXP 'hi(') ORDER BY `users`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
```

For cases like str = "hi)" it works:-

Is there clean rails way of handling the input before it gets executed in regex sql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Safe variant

You could use [`Regexp.escape`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Regexp.html#method-c-escape). It might negate the purpose of using Regexp, though :

For MySQL :

```
def test(str)
  User.where("name REGEXP ?", Regexp.escape(str) ).last
end
```

For Postgres :

```
def test(str)
  User.where("name ~ ?", Regexp.escape(str) ).last
end
```

Test on a local Postgres database :

```
Movie.where("title ~ ?", '*')
#=> PG::InvalidRegularExpression: ERROR:  invalid regular expression: quantifier operand invalid

Movie.where("title ~ ?", Regexp.escape('*'))
#=> [Everything You Always Wanted to Know About Sex * But Were Afraid to Ask]
```

## Unsafe variant

Just make sure your input is correct. With great power comes great responsibility!

```
Movie.where("title ~ ?", 'a{2,}')
#=> [Mou gaan dou, Der Baader Meinhof Komplex, De helaasheid der dingen]

Movie.where("title ~ ?", "\\(").first
#=> (500) Days of Summer

Movie.where("title ~ ?", "[^0-9a-zA-Z \.\-]")
```

For your examples, you'd need `str="hi\\\\"` and `str="hi\\("`